# Something wrong in my sequence of factory creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot, rspec2

I was hoping someone would spot why this wouldn't work.

I am getting an error thats being called because the attributes I specify with Factory_Girl are not being applied to the stub before validation.

**The Error:**

```
undefined method `downcase' for #<Category:0x1056f2f60>
```

**RSpec2**

```
it "should vote up" do
  @mock_vote = Factory.create(:vote)
  Vote.stub(:get_vote).and_return(@mock_vote)
  get :vote_up, :id => "1"        
end
```

**Factories**

```
Factory.define :vote, :class => Vote do |v|
  v.user_id "1"
  v.association :post
end

Factory.define :post, :class => Post do |p|
  p.category "spirituality"
  p.name "sleezy snail potluck"
  p.association :category
end

Factory.define :category, :class => Category do |c|
  c.name "spirituality"
  c.id "37"
end
```

**Post.rb - Model**

```
before_save           :prepare_posts
validate              :category?

def prepare_posts
  self.update_attribute("category", self.category.downcase)
  if self.url?
    self.url = "http://" + self.url unless self.url.match /^(https?|ftp):\/\//
  end
end

def category?
  unless Category.exists?(:name => self.category.downcase)
    errors.add(:category, "There's no categories with that name.")
  end
  return true
end
```

Also, feel free to nitpick any blatantly gross looking code. :D

Thanks!!

Comment: As far as nitpicks, the `:class => Vote/Post/Category` stuff is redundant, because factory_girl will infer the class from your factory name (:vote becomes Vote, :post becomes Post, etc.)

Comment: Ah thought so! Wish their documentation said that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `category` attribute, which appears to be a string, but you also seem to have a category association which automatically creates, among other things, an attribute on Post called `category`, probably overwriting your category attribute. Hence, the `Category` class has no `downcase` method, because it's not a String.

Rename your category attribute to something like `category_name`, but really you shouldn't have that attribute at all.

Maybe where you're calling `self.category.downcase` you meant `self.category.name.downcase`?

Comment: Just trying to wrap my brain around this. I think what you're saying is that the Post downcase method is being passed to its association as well because it has the same name as its attribute? And if I rename it then it would factory it without passing its through the Post model. Why would you suggest I not have that attribute at all?

Comment: `downcase` is an instance method of the String class. You're trying to call it on `self.category` which is a Category object (your model), which doesn't have that method because it's not a String. I'm not sure I understand the rest of your comment.

Comment: Ah but self.category is a string. Because users type in the categories of their posts, I needed to use a string value to relate their posts to categories. So Post has an attribute category. And if that string matches a Category.name, then they match in search results. But even though self.category is a string for Post, it **does** seem like its calling it as the Category model. To which I'm assuming is because the association name is the same name as the attribute?

Comment: If that's the case, then yes, my original answer stands. You have a category **attribute**, and a category **association**. The association is taking precedent and overwriting your attribute. Rename your attribute to category_name.

Comment: Hmm, changing the p.association to p.association :category, :factory => :valid_category doesn't seem to change the error. Even when I removed the p.category from the Post factory, and the validation for in the Category model. Maybe I'm not understanding association :D How does one label Post.category "Any String", and also with it create a Category via Factory.

Comment: I think I get it. Associations are used like relational models, ex: belongs_to etc. In this case, because my two models are connected by strings, it would be innapropriate for me to relate them by association. I should just stub two models in my rspec. On a side note, I can't thank you enough rspeicher. You've been an incredible help.